# Not able to print value of this complex datastructure in perl

Tags: perl

**Question explained as comments in the code:**

I have a following piece of code in which i am trying to make a hash in which the key itself is a reference to some other array.

```
my @arr1=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
my @arr2=(1001,1002,1003);



$FILES_1=\@arr1;
$num1=2;
$FILES_2=\@arr2;
$num2=4;

@FILES=($FILES_1, $FILES_2);
@NUMS=($num1,$num2);
    fun (\@FILES,\@NUMS);





sub fun{

    my ($rFILES,$rNUMS) = @_;

    print "\n --${$rFILES}[0]->[2]  \n "; # This is same as below
    print "\n --$rFILES->[0]->[2]  \n "; # This is same as above

    my %hash=();

    $hash{$rFILES->[0]} = $rNUMS->[0];   

    my $test = $rFILES->[0];
    print "\nTEST : $test->[1]";

    my @key = keys %hash;
    print "\nKey 1 = $key[0]";   # This prints scalar value as below
    print "\ntest  = $test ";   # This prints scalar value as above

    print "\nKey 1->[1] = ${$key[0]}->[1]";  #PROBLEM : THIS DOESNT PRINT SAME AS BELOW
    print "\ntest->[1]  = $test->[1] ";  #THIS PRINTS AS EXPECTED.
}
```

**Output:**

```
 --3

 --3

TEST : 2
Key 1 = ARRAY(0x1bbb540)
test  = ARRAY(0x1bbb540)
Key 1->[1] =
test->[1]  = 2
```

Are we not supposed to keep a key of a hash as reference to some array? Why is the value "2" not printed?

Comment: `use strict;` and then `use warnings;`

Answer (score 3):

A hash key is always a string, you can't store a reference in there. I can't think of a reason you'd want this either.

You should really always `use strict` and `use warnings`. If you added those and declared your variables with `my` properly, you'd have gotten a warning:

`Can't use string ("ARRAY(0x85e628)") as a SCALAR ref while "strict refs" in use`

The syntax you're using:

```
${$key[0]}
```

says `$key[0]` is a reference to a scalar. It isn't, it's a string with the address of what the reference used to be, as you can't use a reference as a hash key they become strings.

**Update:**

You probably want something like this instead:

```
my @filegroups = (
    { number => 1, files => ['file1','file2'] },
    { number => 2, files => ['file3'] },
);
```

Accessed as:

```
foreach my $filegroup ( @$filegroups ) {
    print "my number is $filegroup->{number}\n";
    print "   and I have ".scalar( @{ $filegroup->{ files } } )." files\n";
}
```

If you need extra speed to access the structure by group number (don't bother unless you have hundreds of groups or thousands and thousands of accesses), index them:

```
my %filegroupindexes = map { $_->{ number } => $_ } values @$filegroups;
```

Then you can get to the group like this:

```
print "there are ".scalar( @{ $filegroupindexes{ 1 }->{ files } } )." files in group 1\n";
```

As a last hint, for printing complex data structures [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer) is my favourite:

```
use Data::Printer colored => 1;
p( @filegroups );
```

Comment: thanks for your help :) . Well, This is a situation which frequently can occur. There are various groups of files. And to each group is a number associated. Hence i have made two arrays :one with references to these file groups and other with their aassociated numbers. As per your explanation it seems like i can make a key as a string like "Key1" and their values as $rFILES->[0] and $rNUMS->[0]. But it doesnt make any sense binding a key named "Key1" to these values. Key1 means nothing to these values. It however definitely makes sense to bind $rFiles with rNUMS.

Comment: I've been using Perl professionally for well over a decade for things like system administration type of scripts, data and log processing, database interaction and driving webserver backends, and not once have I felt the need to store something besides a string in a hash key. I'd argue it is poor design, and there are easy ways around it. I'm not entirely sure what it is you're trying to achieve by using data as hash keys, but I'm absolutely sure you do not need it.

Comment: I agree with you that this might be the poor design. But i am now not sure how to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need [Tie::RefHash](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/RefHash.html) if you want to use references as hash keys.

Comment: Nobody needs `Tie::RefHash`.

Comment: @friedo: Kindly explain why?

Comment: just my snarky way of saying that if you are trying to store references in hash keys, you are probably solving the problem the wrong way. Leeft gives a good solution for this problem.

Comment: Oh ok. [7 more to go]